# finding the length given the coordinates for a polygon

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, geometry

I'm working on a question where i need to find the length of the side given the  coordinates of a polygon.
N is the number of rows and 2 is number of columns ( x and y coordinates) and i've collected the coordinates in a multi-dimensional array.

what my idea was to collect the x coordinates in a array say x1 and collect y coordinates in a array say y1. now find the difference between the numbers in the array and perform the distance formula operation. but im not able to proceed any further. im not able to find the length using it as the answer is always short of the actual number. kindly help on how can i find the length of the sides of a given polygon. please find my code below:

```html
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Rope {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  int  N = 1, R=1;
  double AoN=1;
  float d=0 , e=0, f=0, h=0, s=0, length=0, g=0;;
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  int[] arr = new int[2];
  System.out.println("Enter number of Nails (N) and Radius of Nail (R) seperated by space: ");
  for (int i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
   arr[i]=in.nextInt();
  }
  
  if (arr[0]>=1 && arr[0]<=100) {
   N=arr[0]; // N is the number of rows of the multi-dimensional array and rows is fixed to 2 as coordinates are fixed to x and y so 2.
  }
   R=arr[1]; // kindly ignore R as it is used for other purpose.
  
  float[ ][ ] arr1 = new float[N][2];
  System.out.println("Enter Coordinates separated by spaces: ");
  for(int i=0; i<N;i++) {
        for (int j=0;j<2;j++) {
         arr1[i][j]=in.nextFloat();
         //System.out.println(arr1[i][j]);
           }   
       }
  float[] x = new float[N];
  float[] y = new float[N];
  
  for(int i=0; i<N;i++) {
         x[i] = arr1[i][0];
  }
  for (int j=0;j<N;j++) {
         y[j] = arr1[j][1];
  }
  
  for (int i=0; i<x.length-1;i++) {
   d = (float) (d + (Math.pow((x[i+1] - x[i]),2)));
  }
  
  for (int i=0; i<y.length-1;i++) {
   e = (float) (e + (Math.pow((y[i+1] - y[i]),2)));
  }
  
  
  g = d+e;
  s = (float) Math.sqrt(g);
  sysout(s);
  
in.close();
 }

}
```

Comment: Write your algorithm out on paper (as an equation). Is it actually doing what you think it's doing? Compare it to the actual equation of finding distance (point-by-point).  Are they equivalent equations?  Do you remember to find the distance between the last point and the first point?

Comment: yes actually i was struggling with that only. i did write flow of how to go ahead but im facing problem with the distance formula formatting here as a code. taking the x and y coordinates and things like that.

Comment: So what you're doing is summing up the squares of the x distances and summing up the squares of the y distances and then sqrt-ing that sum.  What you need to do is find the distance between each point individually ( sqrt((x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2)) ) and then sum all of those distances. Don't forget the distance between the last and first points.  You don't need separate arrays for this, but it will work.

Comment: thanks. this was helpful. understood how should i write the correct code. thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you have a logical glitch in your code. Here if you notice in the following section :

```
for (int i=0; i<x.length-1;i++) {
            d = (float) (d + (Math.pow((x[i+1] - x[i]),2)));
        }

        for (int i=0; i<y.length-1;i++) {
            e = (float) (e + (Math.pow((y[i+1] - y[i]),2)));
        }
```

Lets say,

```
x1-x2 = X1
x2-x3 = X2
```

and so on

similarly,

```
y1-y2 = Y1
y2-y3 = Y2
```

and so on

now what your code does is it calculates

```
    sqrt(X1*X1 + X2*X2.... +Y1*Y1 + Y2*Y2....)
```

But what actually it is supposed to do is,

```
sqrt(Math.pow((X1-X2),2) + Math.pow(Y1-Y2),2)) + sqrt (Math.pow((X2-X3),2) + Math.pow((Y2-Y3), 2) + ...
```

thus your code generates wrong values.

You should try the following :

```
for (int i=0; i<x.length-1;i++) {
            float temp;

            temp = (Math.pow((x[i+1] - x[i]),2)) + (Math.pow((y[i+1] - y[i]),2));

            d = (float) (d + sqrt(temp));
        }

// for first and last values /  coordinates w.r.t distance formula
for (int i=x.length-1; i<x.length;i++) {
        float temp;

        temp = (float) ((Math.pow((x[i] - x[0]),2)) + (Math.pow((y[i] - y[0]),2)));

        d = (float) (d + Math.sqrt(temp));
    }
```

Instead of that above mentioned two lines.

Hope this helps !!!

Comment: thanks for pointing my mistake. this will work and upon this .. we need to do it for the first and last value too and then sum it on a whole. thanks for the help

Comment: Yeah good point, u need to perform this for the first and last values too